# How it is possible to communicate with HLR through MAP-ATI in GSM network ?

Tags: asterisk, gsm, telecommunication, ati

How it is possible to interact with HLR table through SS7 ? is there any simulator to do that or I'll need to do that through the network operator ? I've been using Astersik to communicate with GSM element but not with HLR table directly , is there any material so I can start with ?

As for example, with RBTs platforms, they platform triggered with every subscriber call, and I would love to achieve such a thing if it is possible, I know that I can do that through Astersik and some AGI to point for some external link, but how could I achieve this with all calls instead of triggered when someone call specific number ?

Any information would be highly appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for the equivalent of an IN (Intelligent Networking) like trigger on each call - i.e. you want an event to be generated and sent to you every time a device or phone makes or receives a call?

In theory operators could offer this as a service so you could then trigger other functions from the event - for example bring up customer information when a particular customer calls.

In practice you may find it hard to find an operator who provides this service - I know of several large operators who do not even have this capability internally (as the event triggering and notification mechanisms add load to very expensive switching equipment so it is hard to justify the cost).

If you can live with just numbers hanging off a particular PABX then you can definitely do this, but I think you already know that from your comment re Astersik above.

Answer (score 0):

Well Asterisk is used for voice over ISUP/SIP. You can communicate with HLR using SIGTRAN or SS7. SIGTRAN communication is simple as compared to SS7as you don't require any ss7 card and a simple server with a network card can with a sigtran stack like [SigtranGateway](http://www.sigtrangateway.com) can be used to communicate with HLR.